# Sending a whatsapp text automatically every X time

Tags: android, whatsapp

I am making a scheduler application that involves several apps and now I am working with whatsapp(which is massively used in my country) and I've checked that the WhatsApp API(which is really restrictive) doesn't allow sending messages automatically. Also I've tried to use an intent to send the text through applications but I want to make it automatically so it doesn't work. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: no mate that would not be achievable presently taking into account server and user security boundaries. closest you can get is open whatsapp through intent to a particular sender/number

Comment: Dang it! Thank you for your response  :)